# Equal expectation and covariance

Tags: statistics, expectation, estimation, covariance

Let $Y_{i}=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}X_{i}+u_{i}$ be the underlying linear relationship between observed values $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ with $u_{i}$ being randomness and/or disturbance term.

Let $\hat\beta_{2}$ be an OLS estimator of the underlying parameter $\beta_{2}$.

When computing $E(\hat\beta_{2} u_{i})$ and $Cov(\hat\beta_{2},u_{i})$, I find that the two have equal values such that $E(\hat\beta_{2} u_{i})=Cov(\hat\beta_{2},u_{i})=\frac{\sigma^{2}x_{i}}{\sum x_{i}^{2}}$.

How can I explain this relationship?

Edit (reconsidering my explanation): Both expressions rely on the subscript of $u_{i}$ because $\hat\beta_{2}$'s randomness comes from the presence of $u_{i}$ in its expression. Not sure how to explain why the 2 expressions are equal though.

Comment: $$\operatorname{Cov}\left(\hat\beta_2,u_i\right) =  \mathbb E\left[\hat\beta_2u_i\right] - \mathbb E\left[\hat\beta_2\right]\mathbb E\left[u_i\right]  $$
and by assumption $\mathbb E\left[u_i\right] = 0$...

Comment: @Math1000, yes exactly! This is what I found numerically. I was wondering if there is any logical/graphical way to explain this though.